# Partly online discrepancy for intervals

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrepancy-theory

Assume that the numbers $\{1,\dots,n\}$ arrive in some unknown order.
Each number needs to be colored red or blue upon arrival.
What is the best discrepancy we can maintain for the intervals?
I know that the answer is between $\log n$ and $\sqrt n$.*

**[Joint work with others](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.13678), of whom I need to share any potentially earned MathOverflow T-shirt I receive in the future because of my increase of reputation due to the upvotes for this question with Dani Gerbner.*

Comment: I think this question needs a few more definitions. In particular, what are the intervals, and what precisely do you mean by "maintain"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor "Intervals" are $\{i,i+1,\dots,j\}$ for some $1 \le i \le j \le n$. "Maintain discrepancy $D$" means that at every step of the process (i.e., after $k$ numbers have arrived for any $k$) the discrepancy is at most $D$. Finally, "discrepancy on an interval" means the absolute value of the number of reds in that interval minus the number of blues in that interval. Please correct me if I am incorrect (about anything).

Comment: The only ambiguity I see is whether the coloring can be randomized. If it must be deterministic, then I don't see why the title would say "partly online" rather than "(fully) online" since if deterministic coloring, then the problem is equivalent to the adversary being adaptive, i.e. choosing the order of the sequence based on the previous colors given. So I think randomness is allowed.

Comment: you can get $3\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$ upper bound without random. idea is to split $[n]$ into $\sqrt{n}$ disjoint intervals of (nearly) equal size, then maintain discrepancy $\le 1$ in each part.

Comment: @Zach Yes, that is precisely our reasoning as well.

Comment: @mathworker21 You are right in the definition. I called in partly online, because in the standard online model the adversary can choose the locations of the newly arriving points arbitrarily, while in this model the places are fixed, just the order of the arrivals varies.

Comment: @domotorp so.... no randomness?

Comment: Not by default, but we're also interested in that version, though we gave it much less thought.